# How do I go on my world on minecraft without being noticed?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Every time I try to be not noticed on my world, my little sister comes and notices me! How do I not be noticed by her?

Comment: My little sister ALWAYS just seeks me out!!! She just comes and builds right near me to annoy me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into your Options menu on iOS, there should be an option that reads "Local Server Multiplayer". By toggling this off, your sister will no longer be able to join your game unless you toggle it back on.

Comment: @MrLemon thx I tested it out and it worked! Thank you SOOO much! :D